# web.input fails in cx_Oracle

Tags: python, web.py, cx-oracle

I have a webserver and I will add the user data into my sql query. It works psycopg but not with cx_Oracle.

```
...
class grid:
    def GET(self):
        web.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        web.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true')
        web.header('Content-Type', 'application/json')

        data = web.input(ID='')
        ido = int(data.ID)
        a = [ido]

        cur = connection.cursor()
        cur.arraysize = 10000

        query = "SELECT a.id AS building_nr, c.geometry.sdo_ordinates AS geometry, d.Classname AS polygon_typ FROM   building a, THEMATIC_SURFACE b, SURFACE_GEOMETRY c, OBJECTCLASS d  WHERE   a.id = b.BUILDING_ID AND b.LOD2_MULTI_SURFACE_ID = c.ROOT_ID AND c.GEOMETRY IS NOT NULL AND b.OBJECTCLASS_ID = d.ID AND a.grid_id_500 = %s;"

        cur.execute(query, a)
```

It works until the execute statement. I get the error message:
**'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 36: ordinal not in range(128)**

How can I add the data into my query?

Answer (score 1):

I know what was wrong. I should not use %s for the data. Apparently, cx_Oracle defaults to a "named" paramstyle .

```
data = web.input(ID='')
query = "SELECT ... FROM... WHERE a.id =:grid_id "
cursor.execute(query, {'grid_id':data.ID})
```

Comment: Yes, use bind variables! Not only do they improve performance but they also improve security (eliminating SQL injection). Note that you can also do the following: cursor.execute(query, grid_id = data.ID) OR you can also do the following cursor.execute("select ... from ... where a.id = :1", [data.ID]). cx_Oracle supports both named parameters using a dictionary or keyword arguments and also numeric parameters using a list.